# Binding Entity Framework results from View Model to View

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I currently have a Datagrid in my views (**ProductView.xaml**) which goes like this:

```
DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" x:FieldModifier="public" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="No MAT" Binding="{Binding MATProductNumber}" Width="0.1*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Format" Binding="{Binding tblFormat.FormatName}" Width="0.1*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom produit" Binding="{Binding tblProduct.ProductName}" Width="0.1*"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

As I am still familiarizing with WPF and C#, I am not still 100% confortable with the MVVM pattern.
I managed to Bind the data to my Datagrid by inserting this code in my **productView.xaml.cs**:

```
public ProductListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadProducts();
    }

private void LoadProducts()
    {
        myDataGrid.ItemsSource = db.tblMATProduct.Include(s => s.tblGrade).Include(s => s.tblProduct).Include(s => s.tblFormat).Take(15).ToList();
    }
```

Here, I set myDataGrid's itemsSource to the result of my Entity Framework query in the **code-behind**.

However, I have read that it is better to implement it in the View Model file instead.

Therefore, I have now binded the Data Context to my View Model in the code-behind and added this to my ViewModel class

```
public ProductListViewModel()
    {
        ProductsList = new List<tblMATProduct>(db.tblMATProduct.Include(s => s.tblGrade).Include(s => s.tblProduct).Include(s => s.tblFormat).Take(15).ToList());
    }

public List<tblMATProduct> ProductsList { get; }
```

And have also modified my Datagrid

```
DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ProductsList}" x:FieldModifier="public" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

But it looks like it's not binding the data.

Does anyone know why is not right in this logic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"myDataGrid's itemsSource... result...Entity Framework...code-behind have read that it is better to implement it in the View Model file instead"_ - not quite.  Whilst it is true that MVVM says it is better to expose the collection in the view model (VM) and have the view (V) bind to it, it says nothing about how the collection is populated.  i.e. MVVM cares not for EF.  You might want to create a service that performs the EF work.  Such a service can then be injected into your VM and during load-time, have the VM call the service to load the model via EF.

Comment: @RandyQuackers: Remove "DataContext." from the binding path.

Comment: That was the problem @mm8. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have done binding of the DataContext after the window is loaded, then there is no need of specifying DataContext while Binding.

DataContext Binding must be your object of ViewModel. So you can directly access the ProductList. By simply following the below code.

```
DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}" x:FieldModifier="public" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```